# laravel won't upload photo

Tags: php, upload, laravel

I just don't get it, why won't it upload the photo.

Having the following in my `Input::all()`:

```
Array
(
    [name] => p17fp1pnaa1gpr5otdg1ba3fd4v.jpg
    [file] => Array
        (
            [name] => tumblr_ltaruq6XCH1qc4lrfo4_400.jpg
            [type] => image/jpeg
            [tmp_name] => C:\xampp\tmp\php9A20.tmp
            [error] => 0
            [size] => 48382
        )

)
```

I try to upload the file to a tmp dir, but it won't do it...

```
$tmp_input = Input::all();
#$tmp_input = $tmp_input['file'];
Input::upload('photo', path('public').'uploads/tmp', $tmp_input['file']['name']);
```

`$tmp_input['file']['name']` or `$tmp_input['name']`, doesn't work either

Yes, the `uploads/tmp` folder exists. Am I missing something from the syntax for which won't it do the upload?

Comment: do you have 'write' access to the tmp folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just so others may know, I had to use `move_uploaded_file()` function as I couldn't upload the file with any function of Laravel.

so this is what I did

```
$tmp_input   = Input::all();
$destination = $this->tmp_dir.$tmp_input['name'];
move_uploaded_file($tmp_input['file']['tmp_name'], $destination);
```

Comment: You should use: 
`$uploadfile=Input::file('userfile');`
`$uploadfile->move($path, $fileName);`

Comment: `Input::upload()` seems to work fine for me in all situations.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are calling the incorrect file name the file in the temp folder once it's uploaded has a different name than the original file if you take a look it's called `[tmp_name] => C:\xampp\tmp\php9A20.tmp`
So the file that you need to move from the temp folder to your `path('public').'uploads/tmp'` It's php9A20.tmp after this you should rename the file with the original name if you will in that case It should be in this way. `[name] => tumblr_ltaruq6XCH1qc4lrfo4_400.jpg`, try the code below.

```
Input::upload('photo', path('public').'uploads/tmp', $tmp_input['file']['tmp_name']);
```